# Read large matrices stored as .txt in Julia

Tags: matrix, import, julia, large-data

I have a matrix saved as ".txt" file of 150k rows X 100k columns that I want to read in Julia. For smaller matrices I have been using readdlm as "x = readdlm("matrix_subset.txt",' ')".
However, for this large matrix it seems not possible to read it, even with 600G of memory. I tried readlines but it reads all as a string. I need "x" to be Array{Float64,2}.

Any ideas?? Thanks!

Comment: `CSV.jl` is great for problems like this, but you'll have to check to docs (or wait for another answerer - late here and I'm going to bed) as I can't remember how it works off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check that! :) I have been using CSV.read to read some tables but i thought it wasn't that efficient

Comment: It should have been improved a lot, or so they say. Be sure that, if you start julia from the command line, you run it with multiple threads patameter, e.g. `julia -t 8`

Comment: "150k rows X 100k columns" of `Float64` is 120GB so you should manage to read it! If you have less memory, most likely you will end parsing line-by-line and use file-mapped `SharedArray` as a storage  https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SharedArrays/#SharedArrays.SharedArray